# How to loop on gpio?

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux, gpio

How can gpio be used to control execution?
The following works for showing the input value of gpio63

```
echo 63 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio63/direction
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value
```

But I've tried a number of things like

```
while [ /sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value = "1" ]
do 
    sleep 1
done
```

without success.

Comment: You're comparing the string "/sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value" to the string "1". They'll never be equal. If you're looking for a "1" as the content of the file named "/sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value" you should say `while [ "$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio64/value)" = 1 ]`

Comment: @AlanCurry The shell can read files directly without pipe/fork/exec cat: `$(</sys/class/gpio/gpio64/value)`

Comment: The large shells (zsh, ksh, bash) can.

Comment: @AlanCurry: thank you very much. This is a small embedded-linux shell. If you copy your answer to a question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing the string "/sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value" to the string "1". They'll never be equal. If you're looking for a "1" as the content of the file named "/sys/class/gpio/gpio63/value" you should say

```
while [ "$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio64/value)" = 1 ]
```